# Clear Macro to clear specific range of cells on Blank cell in certain column

Tags: excel, vba

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40289900/4088852) yesterday to populate a range of cells within a specific list of columns. That aspect of my code is working perfectly, but now I am trying to create a clear macro to delete the inserted rows.

All of the newly inserted rows will have blank cells in column N, so I am simply trying to search all cells in column N, find the blanks, then delete the row between columns N and Y. This is what I have so far, but it is not doing anything when I run it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Clear_PCOTCS()
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    For myRow = myLastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Len(Cells(myRow, "N")) = 1 And Cells(myRow, "N") = "" Then
            Range(Cells(myRow + 1, "N"), Cells(myRow + 1, "Y")).Delete  Shift:=xlDown 'CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End If
    Next myRow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The value in the "N" cell can't have length of 1 *and* be empty.   What are you testing for in that line?

Comment: Thank you, I completely missed that. I have updated that line of code to
    If Cells(myRow, "N") = "" Then

but now I am getting an error on the next line below it

Comment: That `Shift:=xlDown` may be the cause of the error you are getting, that piece of code doesn't do anything there.

Comment: What error message are you getting on that line?

Comment: Well I have formulas in all the cells in column N to Y, so after I delete this particular row, I am trying to shift the cells up so the formula range is not lost

Comment: The error is: Delete method of Range class failed

Comment: So, I'm a little fuzzy.  Why do you test myRow, and then delete the range myRow+1?

Comment: Sorry, so this is the reverse to a macro I ran before that added a row of cells between Column N and Y. So now what I am trying to do, is the reverse. I am trying to find every row between N and Y where the cell in N is blank

Comment: Yeah, xlDown doesn't work.  Maybe you want xlUp?  or nothing at all... and take out the +1 part, I think.

Comment: Well when I removed xlDown it deleted everying in columns N thru Y except the top 3 rows

Comment: xlUp did the same thing, deleted everything but the top 3 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is coming from passing a bad enum to `Range.Delete`.  It expects an [XlDeleteShiftDirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841140.aspx) value, and you're passing it an [XlDirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820880.aspx). Note that although `xlShiftUp` and `xlUp` share the same value, `xlDown` (-4121) is not a valid `XlDeleteShiftDirection`.

If all you need to do is delete every row (between columns "N" and "Y") when the cell in column "N" is empty, you're over-thinking it.  First, the shift should default to `xlShiftUp` based on the shape of the `Range` that you're creating to delete, so you can simply omit the parameter.  Second, you need to remove the offset you're applying here:

```
Range(Cells(myRow + 1, "N"), Cells(myRow + 1, "Y")).Delete
```

Delete the row that you're testing, not the one below it. You should be looking for something more like this:

```
Sub Clear_PCOTCS()
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
    For myRow = myLastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(myRow, 14).Value = vbNullString Then
            Range(Cells(myRow, 14), Cells(myRow, 25)).Delete
        End If
    Next myRow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply. That worked perfectly, but unfortunately it also deleted the formulas I had in my cells in that range. Is there a way to only delete the rows that have a blank N cell value, but not those with saved formulas?

Comment: @B.Price - Do you mean cells in column N that have formulas that return an empty string, or only rows where *all* columns are empty?

Comment: Sorry, ok so before I run any macros, the cell range of N10:R500 has a formula in each cell that populates data as it is entered elsewhere on the sheet. 

I then have a macro that will enter new rows between columns N and R . MY clear macro is trying to just clear those added rows, and not the other empty rows that have the formulas in them, in essence returning the sheet back to its status prior to both macros being used. That is why I had the ShiftUp logic in my clear macro

Comment: Another approach I can use is to clear the entire range except the formulas? Is that possible?

Comment: @B.Price - How the worksheet got to the state that it's in before you run the macro isn't relevant. If you only want to delete rows without formulas *or* values in column N, change the `If Cells(myRow, 14).Value = vbNullString Then` line to `If IsEmpty(Cells(myRow, 14)) Then`.

Comment: Was thinking of something like this but modified to fit my needs. I have never used this function before though. Would have to fix it to my range

    .Cells.SpecialCells _
              (xlCellTypeConstants, "N").ClearContents

Comment: Wow that did it. So simple! Thank you for your help again!